# documentation not showing for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I download "Documentation for Android SDK" in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. It shows the documentation for most things but it's not showing for `RecyclerView`. Why?

[image: what I get when I ask for documentation of RecyclerView stuff]

**Edit #1**

It also doesn't show for LinearLayoutManager which comes from the same place:
`android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager`

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to get documentation for android would be to install the [AndroidSourceViewer](https://github.com/pengwei1024/AndroidSourceViewer) plugin. You can install it by clicking on File > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories > Search for AndroidSourceViewer and install the plugin. You may have to restart Android Studio for it finish installation.

Usage:

Simply right click on the element that you want to get documentation for. Then in the menu select Android Developer Reference. This will open up the documentation in your web browser.